# How do I evaluate an expression in bash and assign the value to a variable?

Tags: bash

I have an expression like this:

```
if [[ $s == *Mar* ]]; then "match"; else "not"; fi;
```

How do assign its value to a variable?
command substitution syntax does not work, because bash tries to evaluate the result of the expression:

```
x=$(if [[ $s == *Mar* ]]; then "match"; else "not"; fi;)
```

gives the error:

```
-bash: match: command not found
```

So, basically I want to tell bash to evaluate an expression, but do not treat the output as a command.
How do I do that?

Comment: You're confusing cause and effect.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams, would you care to elaborate?

Comment: Don't need to; it's already covered below.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
if [[ $s == Mar ]]; then "match"; else "not"; fi
```

is not an *expression*; it is a *command*. You could make it into a command that outputs either `match` or `not` by inserting appropriate `echo` commands, and then capture the output with backticks or `$()`.

But that would be pointlessly indirect. Why not simply

```
if [[ $s == Mar ]]; then
  x="match"
else
  x="not"
fi
```

?

Comment: I agree with the current comments and this post. To make explicit what Henning has said, x=$( if [[ $s == "Mar" ]] then echo "match" ; else echo "not" ; fi ) will do what you asked. Finally, you might want to research the `eval` command, as it also supports 'evaluat(ing) the result of the expression'. Good luck.

Comment: @shellter, your answer is the one I was looking for. Could you add it as an answer so that I can accept it?

Comment: Thanks, but I think @HenningMakholm did answer your question. Please give him the credit :-) Good luck to all.

Comment: @Sali, so you real question is, "how can I write this in the most inefficient and language-abusive way possible"? In that case you should probably rewrite shellter's suggestion to use `echo "match" | cat` instead of plain `echo "match"`. Much more enterprisey that way.

Comment: @HenningMakholm, your answer shows the way it is generally done/should be done in bash script. And it is fine. My question was more along the line of how I can assign the result to a variable. My bash concepts are not clear and the ensuing discussion based on your answer helped me understand the concept well. Thanks for that.